# Formatting date in xslt 2 for 2 digits

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to format a certain date format in xslt. This is the format:
05/08/2015

I'd like to convert this in xslt, so that the above would become:
050815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT, `05/08/2015` is not a date - it's a meaningless string. To convert it to `050815`, you can use string manipulation:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($datestring, 1, 2), substring($datestring, 4, 2), substring($datestring, 9, 2)) "/>
```

Comment: ..Thanks for the answer, its works. The given date i put  just as an example.

Comment: BTW.. i modified it further as <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[M01][D01]')" /> <xsl:value-of select="substring(format-date(current-date(), '[Y0001]'), 3, 2)" />

Comment: @Bunty That makes no sense. If you're starting with a **real** date - such the output of `current-date()`, then you only need to do: `format-date(current-date(), '[M01][D01][Y01]')` to get `080515` (today).

Comment: [Y01] is giving me 2015 not 15

Comment: It works for me using Saxon: http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKx8. How about `[Y, *-2]`?

Comment: wow [Y, *-2] worked. I'm using saxon 8.7,but still [Y01] is not working for me for desired output.

Comment: `[Y01]` works in Saxon 8.9, so that must be a bug. In any case, `[Y, *-2]` is another way to get the same result.

Comment: Saxon 8.7 was released in June 2006, *before* the final XSLT 2.0 recommendation. Its high time you moved forward.